# portable iTunes alternative for windows compatible with iPhone

Tags: itunes, ipod, software-rec

I am looking for a portable alternative to iTunes to work with my iPhone so that I could sync with the company computer without iTunes on it. Would like it to be able to access the app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) is pretty good and i hear it can sync with iphones. I'm not familiar with any non-itunes application that can access the iTunes store though.

Answer (score 1):

[DoubleTwist](http://doubletwist.com)